# Css text styling with image

Tags: css, background-image, image-size

I'm styling my letters using an image as the content of the letters.
The letters are small and the image big, and I would like to have more control over the image size. What is the css properties to do so?

```
 background-image: url(https://files.cargocollective.com/c2106023/Menu.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip:text;
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You should provide some HTML with your CSS in a demo snippet.

Comment: Are you saying you want the background image to be just big enough to be behind all the characters, but no bigger?

Comment: what I mean is I would like to resize my image to see what size I like. The other answer helped me figure it out. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi Isherwood. Thank you. I will do so next time.

Answer (score 2):

To have more control over the size of the background image within the letters, you can adjust the background-size property to specific dimensions. Here's how you can modify your CSS:

```css
background-image: url(https://files.cargocollective.com/c2106023/Menu.jpg);
background-size: 50px 50px; /* Adjust the dimensions as needed */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Prevent the image from repeating */
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
```

For your case you can keep, background-size: 50px 50px; which sets the size of the background image to 50 pixels in width and 50 pixels in height. You can change these values according to your requirements to get the desired size for the background image.